# using polymer iron-selector events

Tags: javascript, polymer, dhtml

Here is the (abridged) code I am using with iron-selector

```
...
<iron-selector id="listSelection" attr-for-selected="name" on-tap="_itemSelected">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{boilerplateSets}}">
      <div class="item" name='{{item.name}}'>
        <paper-icon-item >
          <paper-item-body two-line>
            <div>{{item.name}}</div>
            <div secondary>{{item.description}}</div>
          </paper-item-body>
          <iron-icon class="big-icon" icon="hardware:keyboard-arrow-right"></iron-icon>
        </paper-icon-item>
        <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
      </div>
    </template>
...
```

Followed by this script (also abridged)

```
<script>
Polymer
(
    {
        is: 'boilerplate-list',
        ready: function()
        {
        this.boilerplateSets = [{name: 'CVs', description: 'Bolierplates'},
                               {name: 'Addresses', description:                                    
                               'Boilerplates'},];
        },
        behaviors: 
        [
            Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior
        ],
        _itemSelected: function(e,detail)
         {
                 console.log("selected e:" + e.name);
                 console.log("selected detail:" + detail.name);

                 var _selected = this.$.listSelection.selectedItem;
                 console.log('selected item:' + _selected);
                 this.fire('select',{item: _selected});
        },
      ...
    }
);
</script>
```

I am struggling on two fronts:

1. what configuration including which attribute/property do I use to access the value of the selected item? In this example I have **tried** to configure it to use the "name" value. This does not work in this example. I have had it working, but can not recall how; permutations might include "item.name" or "{{name}}" or "{{item.name}}".
2. I am have is a race condition. The on-tap event fires and calls _ItemSlected. But when I read the values in this function they are not updated. The second time I tap and get the event to fire the values are now set, but to accurate to the last selection.

I'd really value a decent example of iron-selector being used with binding (ie with {}) and with events firing including the use of the arr-for-selected and on-tap event.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your first problem, you can use `itemForElement` in your `_itemSelected` handler:

```
this.$.myList.itemForElement(e.target);
```

Where `myList` is an `id` attribute on the `dom-repeat` template.

```
<iron-selector>
    <template id="myList" is="dom-repeat" items="{{someItems}}"></template>
</iron-selector>
```

I am not sure about the race condition problem. Where I have done this I have actually put the `on-tap` event on (in your example) `<div class="item">`.

Comment: Thank you @CriagLoftus. That solved both of my problems. How to access the value and the race condition. 

If you wanted to follow up with any links to good examples (something you wrote perhaps) ....

But you have done enough. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulArmstrong I only solved this problem for myself yesterday. It is not an ideal solution, and I expect there is a better solution that allows for easier binding using `Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior` instead of `iron-selector`.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with the whole "race condition" issue. Instead of using "on-tap", I used "on-iron-select". This ensures that the function will not be called until a selection has first been made.

So with your code, change this:

```
    <iron-selector id="listSelection" attr-for-selected="name" on-tap="_itemSelected">
```

to this:

```
    <iron-selector id="listSelection" attr-for-selected="name" on-iron-select="_itemSelected">
```

Hopefully that helps anyone else that is having this problem.